# I want to add constructor.name to a custom javascript class project

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, jquery-plugins

I use [this](https://github.com/jiem/my-class) small class function for my javascript code; actually it is somehow altered in the way it '*implements*' other classes so that it '*inherets*' only functions and not properties (see it at: https://github.com/centurianii/g3OO).

The problem is that it:

1) doesn't give a `<object>.constructor.name`, see No.3 and 4 at http://jsfiddle.net/A8SkN/3/ (eventually what I want is somehow to have the name of the new class which is stored in a variable-I know it's a complete madness compared with proper OO languages) and

2) doesn't pass any specific static property with name `name` (but it sees everything else as long as it has a different name!), see No.6 at jsfiddle above.

Here is the `Class` code:

```
(function(window, document, undefined){
   // Namespace object
   var g3;
   // Return as AMD module or attach to head object
   if (typeof define !== 'undefined')
      define([], function () {
         g3 = g3 || {};
         return g3;
      });
   else if (typeof window !== 'undefined')
      g3 = window.g3 = window.g3 || {};
   else{
      g3 = g3 || {};
      module.exports = g3;
   }

   g3.Class = function () {
      var len = arguments.length;
      if(len === 0 || (len === 1 && arguments[0] === null))
         return function() {};
      var body = arguments[len - 1],
          SuperClass = len > 1 ? arguments[0] : null,
          implementClasses = len > 2,
          Class,
          SuperClassEmpty,
          i;

      //we expect last object to override 'constructor' otherwise the new is empty!
      if (body.constructor === Object) {
         Class = function() {};
      } else {
         Class = body.constructor;
         delete body.constructor;
      }

      //'Class.Super' is a reserved word for g3.Class!
      if (SuperClass) {
         SuperClassEmpty = function() {};
         SuperClassEmpty.prototype = SuperClass.prototype;
         Class.prototype = new SuperClassEmpty();
         Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
         //doesn't work!
         //Class.prototype.constructor.name = Class.prototype.toString();
         Class.Super = SuperClass;
         extend(Class, SuperClass, false); //works for static members!
      }

      if (implementClasses)
         for (i = 1; i < len - 1; i++)
            if(typeof arguments[i] === 'object')
               extend(Class.prototype, arguments[i], false, 'function');
            else
               extend(Class.prototype, arguments[i].prototype, false);

      extendClass(Class, body);

      return Class;
   };

   function extendClass(Class, extension, override) {
      //'STATIC' is a reserved word from last argument of g3.Class!
      if (extension.STATIC) {
         extend(Class, extension.STATIC, override); //overwrites previous parent's static members
         delete extension.STATIC;
      }
      extend(Class.prototype, extension, override);
   };

   var extend = g3.Class.extend = function (obj, extension, override, type) {
      var prop;
      if (override === false) {
         for (prop in extension)
            if (!(prop in obj))
               if(!type)
                  obj[prop] = extension[prop];
               else if(typeof extension[prop] === type)
                  obj[prop] = extension[prop];
      } else {
         for (prop in extension)
            if(!type)
               obj[prop] = extension[prop];
            else if(typeof extension[prop] === type)
               obj[prop] = extension[prop];
         if (extension.toString !== Object.prototype.toString)
            obj.toString = extension.toString;
      }
   };
}(window, document));
```

Let's test `Class`:

```
///////TESTS///////
function Person(name){
   this.name = name;
}

//Class Dreamer extends Person
var Dreamer = g3.Class(Person, {
   STATIC: {
       dreams: [],
       name: 'Dreamer'
   },
   constructor: function(name, dream) {
      //Explicit call to Dreamer.Super === Person
      Dreamer.Super.call(this, name);
      this.dream = dream;
   },
   add: function() {
      Dreamer.dreams.push(this.dream);
   },
    toString: function(){
        return 'Dreamer';
    }
});
var poet = new Dreamer('Hary', 'I\'ll write a poem today!');
poet.add();

/////PRINT/////
var tests =  '<ol><li>poet.toString() = ' +  poet.toString() + '</li>';
tests += '<li>poet.constructor = ' + poet.constructor + '</li>';
tests += '<li>poet.constructor.name = ' + poet.constructor.name + '</li>';
tests += '<li>poet.constructor.name == \'\' : ' + (poet.constructor.name === '')+ '</li>';
tests += '<li>poet.prototype = ' + poet.prototype + '</li>';
if(poet.prototype)
tests += '<li>poet.prototype.constructor = ' + poet.prototype.constructor + '</li>';
tests += '<li>Dreamer.name = ' + Dreamer.name + '</li>';
tests += '<li>Dreamer.dreams = ' + Dreamer.dreams + '</li>';

document.getElementById('class').innerHTML = tests + '</ol>';
```

The results:

```
1. poet.toString() = Dreamer
2. poet.constructor = function (name, dream)...
3. poet.constructor.name =
4. poet.constructor.name == '' : true   //empty string!
5. poet.prototype = undefined
6. Dreamer.name =                       //empty string!
7. Dreamer.dreams = I'll write a poem today!
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: too much code and too much explanation, need to narrow your issue down to specifics with only relevant code present

Comment: ok, I rephrased it leaving just my 2 questions.

Comment: I also posted this issue at the developer's project....